# how to fix tab bar to bottom of mobile screen while scrolling without animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a tab bar that is fixed to the bottom of the screen in mobile.

When I scroll the page up, there is a 'glitch' - the tab bar hangs in its position for 1sec before suddenly dropping to the bottom of the screen.

How do I remove this glitch or animation ?

Below is my code:

```
.mobile-nav-overlay {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99999;
    background: #ebe7dd;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-top: 1px solid #d2cec5;
}
```

Comment: That code looks fine. Do you have more CSS that you could post? Maybe something else is causing that...

Comment: Sounds like it _could_ be a job for [`position: sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning)... but I agree w/ Bruno that it would be helpful to have more code/a [mcve] to get a better sense of the issue being faced.

Comment: Mobile browsers usually hide and unhide the address bar depending on the direction and distance scrolled, which messes with the window height. Might be worth looking into if this is causing the issue.

Comment: @AlexanderNied position: sticky; works but now it shifted to the top. How do I stick it to the bottom ?

Comment: add `bottom: 0px;`